# How to remove a field in Tarantool space?

Tags: tarantool, tarantool-cartridge

I have field in tarantool space I no longer need.

```lua
local space = box.schema.space.create('my_space', {if_not_exists = true})
space:format({
        {'field_1', 'unsigned'},
        {'field_2', 'unsigned'},
        {'field_3', 'string'},
})
```

How to remove `field_2` if it's indexed and if it's not indexed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any convenient way to do it.

The first way, just declare this field as nullable and insert `NULL` value to this field. Yes, it will be stored physically but you could hide them from users.
It's simple and not expensive.

The second way, write in-place migration. It's not possible if you have indexed fields after field you want to drop (in your example it's `field_3`).
And it's dangerous if you have a huge amount of data in this space.

```lua
local space = box.schema.space.create('my_space', {if_not_exists = true})
space:create_index('id', {parts = {{field = 1, type = 'unsigned'}}})
space:format({
    {'field_1', 'unsigned'},
    {'field_2', 'unsigned'},
    {'field_3', 'string'},
})

-- Create key_def instance to simplify primary key extraction
local key_def = require('key_def').new(space.index[0].parts)

-- drop previous format
space:format({})

-- Migrate your data
for _, tuple in space:pairs() do 
    space:depete(key_def:extract_key(tuple))
    space:replace({tuple[1], tuple[3]})
end

-- Setup new format
space:format({
    {'field_1', 'unsigned'},
    {'field_3', 'string'},
})
```

The third way is to create new space, migrate data into it and drop previous.
Still it's quite dangerous.

```lua
local space = box.schema.space.create('new_my_space', {if_not_exists = true})
space:create_index('id', {parts = {{field = 1, type = 'unsigned'}}})
space:format({
    {'field_1', 'unsigned'},
    {'field_3', 'string'},
})

-- Migrate your data
for _, tuple in box.space['my_space']:pairs() do 
    space:replace({tuple[1], tuple[3]})
end

-- Drop the old space
box.space['my_space']:drop()

-- Rename new space
local space_id = box.space._space.index.name:get({'my_new_space'}).id

-- In newer version of Tarantool (2.6+) space.alter method available
-- But in older versions you could update name via system "_space" space 
box.space._space:update({space_id}, {{'=', 'name', 'my_space'}})
```